# Resolved : Get last 3 items created

Tags: vue.js, symfony4, api-platform.com

I want to create an API (GET) to render a part of my created items (the last 3 of them ordered by recent date).
These items will render into a Vue.js block.
I don't know if I used a simple operation or if I create a collection or a data provider. I am a newbie with Api Platform and I want to do things good.

I search how to create a custom operation, collection and dataProvider but I don't know which is the good way to get the last items.

Thank you a lot for your advices (thx @MinDBreaK)

Edit:

Here my solution :

```
/*
 * @ApiResource(
 * attributes={"pagination_client_items_per_page"=true},
 * collectionOperations={
 *     "post",
 *     "get",
 *     "get_last_test"={
 *         "method"="GET",
 *         "path"="/test",
 *         "controller"=ToDoSomething::class,
 *         "maximum_items_per_page"=3
 *     }
 * })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use pagination for example for this, by specifing the number of elements you want.

Here is the link to the documentation explaining this : https://api-platform.com/docs/core/pagination/

And more precisely if you want it only for a single entity : https://api-platform.com/docs/core/pagination/#for-a-specific-resource-3

Comment: Yes you're right!! Thank you a lot. With the documentation and some chocolate, here my solution:

/*
 * @ApiResource(
 * attributes={"pagination_client_items_per_page"=true},
 * collectionOperations={
 *     "post",
 *     "get",
 *     "get_last_test"={
 *         "method"="GET",
 *         "path"="/test",
 *         "controller"=YourControllerToDoSomething::class,
 *         "maximum_items_per_page"=3
 *     }
 * })